# IntelliJ IDEA CE does not recognise `java.util` import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6 and it does not seem to mark `java.util` namespace as properly imported. I can compile with no problems though, the only issue is the syntax highlighting.

I understand that the CE edition has limitations, but I guess this is not one of them. (or am I wrong?)

Any way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project SDK (Set Java there)

Comment: Fix your JDK/SDK, invalidate caches.

Comment: java newbie mistake :D thanks!

Comment: You should have a yellow bar at the top telling you this is a problem, and a way to fix it.